# Mask user entered passwords in Microsoft Bot Framework V4 Nodejs

Tags: azure, botframework, skype

I am using the botframework sdk4 nodejs and I am mostly going to deploy the bot on skype channel. I need to verify the user of the bot and for that I am asking the user their credentials in the bot. But I need to mask the passwords, is there a way I can do it? Is there a card available in the bot sdk that has fields for username and passwords?

Currently in test phase, I am just directly asking the user for a username and password, as normal text inputs. But this is not at all secure to be deployed.

Please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: "I am asking the user their credentials in the bot." soooo... your user credentials will be stored in the conversation data and possible logs (if you have logs implemented, which would be a best practice) for example. That's not a good idea. What do you want to verify: a user/pwd? Can't you use the user identity provided by the channel?

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to comment for the moment but please have a look at open discussion here :
[microsoft/AdaptiveCards](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/1443)